# Flatten Nested Subscriptions in Angular2

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, subscription

In an Angular2 component I am subscribing to the `activatedRoute` and using one of the route's parameters, makes an HTTP `get` request.

It seems I need to subscribe to both the `activatedRoute.params` and `http.get` Observables — the latter nested inside the former.

In effect I am nesting my subscriptions which I am sure could (and *should*) be flattened.

I believe I can use RxJs for this but I am no expert!

The following component works, but I believe can be improved upon. Your suggestions are greatly appreciated!

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

import {
  AngularFireDatabase,
  FirebaseListObservable
} from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';

import { GridService } from '../grid.service';
import { SquareMetadata } from '../square-metadata';
import { SquareService } from '../square.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'pu-grid',
  templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid.component.scss']
})
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
  public list: FirebaseListObservable<SquareMetadata[]>;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private gridService: GridService,
    private http: Http,
    private squareService: SquareService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
      this.http.get('https://pu2-dev.firebaseio.com/squareMetadata/' + params.key + '.json?shallow=true')
        .map((response: Response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .subscribe((keys: Array<string>) => {
          console.log(keys);
        }, (error) => {
          console.log(error);
        });

      this.gridService.activatedGrid = params.key;
      this.list = this.squareService.list;
    });
  }
}
```

### Update (based on atomrc's answer):

I have refactored my `ngOnInit` function as per **atomrc's** answer but I now receive an error and the app fails when navigating to routes that use this component.

Here's my refactor so far:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.activatedRoute.params.mergeMap((params: Params) => {
    return this.http.get('https://pu2-dev.firebaseio.com/squareMetadata/-KnGq1D89F4pdCH_vjhs.json?shallow=true')
  })
  .map((response: Response) => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .subscribe((keys: Array<string>) => {
    console.log(keys);
  }, (error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
}
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: undefined is not a function (near '....map(function (response)...')
```

In addition, if you notice in my original code, towards the bottom of the `activatedRoute.params` subscription I have the line `this.gridService.activatedGrid = params.key;`

In the refactor this would need to move into the subscriptions success callback. But `params.key` wouldn't be available there.

Therefore I feel this isn't the solution I was after, after all.

Thank you for your help thus far!

## Update: Working :-)

For future reference, the following is my working refactor:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params, Router } from '@angular/router';

import {
  AngularFireDatabase,
  FirebaseListObservable
} from 'angularfire2/database';
import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/mergeMap';

import { GridService } from '../grid.service';
import { Shallow } from '../shallow';
import { SquareMetadata } from '../square-metadata';
import { SquareService } from '../square.service';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'pu-grid',
  templateUrl: './grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./grid.component.scss']
})
export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
  public list: FirebaseListObservable<SquareMetadata[]>;

  constructor(
    private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private gridService: GridService,
    private http: Http,
    private router: Router,
    private squareService: SquareService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.params.mergeMap((params: Params) => {
      let path: string = [
        environment.firebaseAppConfig.databaseURL,
        'squareMetadata',
        params.key
      ].join('/');

      return this.http.get([ path, '.json?shallow=true' ].join(''))
        .map((response: Response) => {
          return response.json();
        })
        .map((json: Shallow) => {
          return { key: params.key, json: json };
        });
    })
    .subscribe(({ key, json }: { key: string, json: Shallow }) => {
      if (json) {
        this.gridService.activatedGrid = key;
        this.list = this.squareService.list;
      } else {
        this.router.navigate([ '' ]);
      }
    }, (error: Error) => {
      throw new Error(error.message);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: atomrc posted the correct answer. There is an excellent guide to this, and more of the most practical features of observables here: https://gist.github.com/staltz/868e7e9bc2a7b8c1f754

Comment: Thank you @Murphy4 I'll be sure to read this over the weekend. I've refactored based on atomrc's suggestion but still run into an error — I'd be grateful for your input/suggestions on this too! Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are totally right, flattening is the thing to do here :)

With rxjs, the operator you are looking for is `mergeMap`. 
Here is what you can do

```
this.activatedRoute.params
  .mergeMap((params) => {
    return this.http.get('https://example.com/' + params.key)
      .map(response => response.json())

      // build a new object from the response's data and the params
      .map(data => ({ params: params, data: data }))
  })
  .subscribe(({ params, data }) => {
    this.gridService.activatedGrid = params.key;
    // do stuff with `data`
  });
```

Comment: Thanks so much — I'd been playing around with `mergeMap` and `switchMap` for hours before this! I've tried your suggestion though and now run into an error so I've updated my question. Would you be able to take a look?

Comment: Hum weird indeed. BTW I did see the `this.gridService.activatedGrid = params.key;` that depends on the params. Will update my answer then :)

Comment: Here is an updated version passing the `params` down to the subscribe. I am not sure what could happen with the error you get. Could it be from elsewhere in the code?

Comment: The error seems to be in a promise, and I don't see any promise (except for `response.json()`) in your code ...

Comment: I have to admit, I am confused by `res.json()`. Angular's doc says it follows the `fetch` spec, but it seems to be returning an object, not a promise https://angular.io/guide/http#parse-to-json

Comment: That link says it should convert the response into an Object — which it's doing? Does the `fetch` spec say it should be a promise? Anyhow it all works now and I've updated with my working refactor. Didn't need the `Observable` and `fromPromise` in the end. Out of interest; is it good practice to have all those type definitions — or is my OCD making me a bit obsessive?

Comment: Yes the fetch spec says `res.json` should return a promise. Quickly after reading your question I asked this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44726114/is-angular-really-following-the-fetchs-specifications/44726591 so it seems angular is wrong with it's fetch implementation. That's why I got confused with the `fromPromise`. But you are right you don't need it (I fixed my answer accordingly :))

Comment: And BTW I things it's a very good practice to have all those types. It helps you defining clear contracts between all the pieces of your code 