# Is angular really following the fetch's specifications?

Tags: javascript, angular, http, fetch

The Angular's `http` docs says that the response returned by the `http` service follows the `fetch` specification.

https://angular.io/guide/http#parse-to-json

And in their example, this is the code you can find

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body.data || { };
}
```

In which, obviously, the result of `res.json()` is **not a promise**.

But in the `fetch` specification, the `response.json()` method is supposed to return a `Promise`.

https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#response-class

Am I missing something in the `fetch` spec or is Angular wrong about it's implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking into angular's http source it's clear it doesn't return a Promise:

```
 json(): any {
    if (typeof this._body === 'string') {
      return JSON.parse(<string>this._body);
    }

    if (this._body instanceof ArrayBuffer) {
      return JSON.parse(this.text());
    }

    return this._body;
  }

  // source https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/body.ts#L26
```

But the spec says

```
[NoInterfaceObject, Exposed=(Window,Worker)]
interface Body {
  readonly attribute ReadableStream? body;
  readonly attribute boolean bodyUsed;
  [NewObject] Promise<ArrayBuffer> arrayBuffer();
  [NewObject] Promise<Blob> blob();
  [NewObject] Promise<FormData> formData();
  [NewObject] Promise<any> json();
  [NewObject] Promise<USVString> text();
};
```

So it seems that angular decided not to follow the spec strictly.

Comment: Indeed this line of the spec is confusing. In the MDN it is clearly a promise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Body/json and in the spec, the signature of `json` is `[NewObject] Promise<any> json();` https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#body-mixin

Comment: To me is clear that it must return a Promise. A promise IS an object and every `json()` call should return a NEW Promise obj, not the same reference (as the spec says).

Comment: Totally agreed. There might be a reason for the angular team to chose not to return a promise. I might investigate that matter :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you're right (because of [consume body algo](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-body-consume-body)), they aren't following the spec for `fetch`, internally they are using `JSON.parse` to parse the JSON (see: [github](http://%20https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/http/src/body.ts#L26)).

I think they're doing it to propagate the error more easily up the callstack, so the user can easily catch it himself via `http.get().catch()`. But for more information try to ask them directly via [gitter](https://gitter.im/angular/angular).